# iOS 11 iPhone x navigation bar has a gap between notch

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, ios11, iphone-x

On pressing the comment icon its loading and pushing CommentController to the Navigation stack.

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CommentsVC") as! CommentsController
    controller.post = post
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
```

Strange thing is that NavigationBar is perfect in first screen. HomeFeed(first screen) is embedded in the navigationController using storyboard.

[image: Illustration:]

Comment: Can you pls highlight which gap you are talking about ?

Comment: torap, i have highlighted the image. i am talking about the black gap on the top of commentController. NavigationBar is not attached to the top of the screen like homeFeed screen NavigationBar.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the navigation bar in iOS11 iPhoneX does not reach the top.

You can turn it white by doing `window?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white` in your app delegate.

However, I would suggest reviewing your hierarchy. This shouldn't happen in this case.